# will git hash length change with the SHA256 transition?

Tags: git, sha1, sha256

as stated here, https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ed8d8da374f648764758f13038ca93af87ab800 since ~2018, there's been plans to switch out git's hash algorithm from SHA1 to SHA256

will that be a truncated SHA256, or is git's hash lengths going to change?

Comment: Probably best to read the transition plan: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/hash-function-transition.txt

Comment: Yes, the length will change. Some people may show the new hashes using `--abbrev=40` making it hard to tell if you have a new or old hash. Read the transition plan, and expect practical problems to crop up in practice and to have in-practice (i.e., ad-hoc) solutions added.